# Пунктуация при сочетании двух вопросов

Tags: пунктуация

— Не знаю, что я тут делаю. — Как, что делаешь? Ищешь меня.

Возможна ли подобная пунктуация (после "как" — запятая)? Или лучше "что делать" закавычить? Или совсем ничего не ставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Не знаю, что я тут делаю. ― Как что делаешь? Ищешь меня.***

II. частица. 1. Употр. для выражения удивления, негодования, сомнения и т.п. по какому-л. поводу.

Примеры:

― Что это? ― удивился Тумаш. ― Как что? ― хихикнул лейтенант. ― Или без парашюта спрыгнешь ― не высоко ли будет? [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)

― Ну и что из этого? ― Как что из этого? Очень даже много из этого. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 5 (1978)]

Comment: Простите, но, думаю, надо уточнить Ваш ответ. **_II. частица._** — о чем это? И где возможно посмотреть?

Comment: Словарь Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру